# Link object files without libSystem macOS

Tags: macos, linker, x86-64, linker-errors, ld

I'm writing a compiler for macOS on x86-64, but when I link the object files together, `ld` says

```
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for inferred architecture x86_64
```

But since libSystem contains libc, I don't want to use it (it would give me lots of duplicates). How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-macosx_version_min 10.6` as `ld` parameter. This will generate `LC_UNIXTHREAD` instead of `LC_MAIN` in your executable. If you want even more control you'd need to get rid of `ld` in your chain altogether.