# nasm - Can't link object file with ld on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, ld

I'm trying to assemble a simple Hello World, which worked fine in the previous macOS version:

```
        global   start
        section  .text
start:  mov      rax, 0x02000004
        mov      rdi, 1
        mov      rsi, msg
        mov      rdx, 13
        syscall
        mov      rax, 0x02000001
        xor      rdi, rdi
        syscall

        section  .data
msg:    db       "Hello world!", 10
```

Then I use `nasm` and `ld` as I did before:

```
$ nasm -f macho64 hello.asm
$ ld hello.o -o hello
```

But `ld` gives me the following error:

```
ld: warning: No version-min specified on command line
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

I tried switching `start` to `_main`, but got the following:

```
ld: warning: No version-min specified on command line
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for inferred architecture x86_64
```

Don't even know what that might mean.

Comment: This is why you'd normally link with `cc hello.o -o hello`, because C compilers know how to link object files into executables.  BTW, you should use `lea rdi, [rel msg]`, instead of the `mov rdi, imm64` absolute form that requires runtime relocation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`ld` needs `-lSystem` flag to prevent it from throwing this error. Also it needs `-macosx_version_min` to remove the warning. The correct way of using `ld` would be: `ld hello.o -o hello -macosx_version_min 10.13 -lSystem`.

*Updated* on macOS 11 and above, you need to pass `-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib` as well so that it locates the `-lSystem` library correctly. You can use `-L$(xcode-select -p)/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib` to evaluate the right path dynamically if required.

Comment: With `10.13` as min version `ld` switches to load command `LC_MAIN` entry point convention handled by `dyld`.  You're system exit call forces the process to exit without giving chance to `dyld` to flush buffers (which is irrelevant for system write call, but not for `printf`). See my answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810074/5329717 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48252805/5329717

Comment: So what is the full command to run this hello.asm? I'm using the same tutorial and just replacing your `ld` doesn't work.

Comment: for learning LC_MAIN, https://h3adsh0tzz.com/2020/01/macho-file-format/

Comment: @MoteZart full command for me is:
`nasm -f macho64 program.asm && ld -macosx_version_min 12.6.0 -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem -o program program.o && ./program`

Answer (score 16):

*In addition to the @Verloren answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52830915/1189569)*

I had an issue with macOS Big Sur (macOS 11.1), where flag `-lSystem` could not locate `libSystem.dylib`, with the error

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
```

I found out for macOS Big Sur, quoted from the link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11_0_1-release-notes

> New in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, the system ships with a built-in dynamic
> linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change,
> copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem.
> Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking
> for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail...

that all copies of dynamic libraries are not located in `usr/lib/` and similar, so flag `-lSystem` could not found `libSystem.dylib` by default.

The solution to this was to update/install the latest version of Command Line Tools, if not already, and to set flag `-L` of the `ld` command to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib`.

So full command would look like this:

```
ld hello.o -o hello -macosx_version_min 11.0 -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful.

Comment: Still works fine on Monterey with the latest Command Line Tools installed. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Simpler answer. *ld* is defaulting to dynamic linking and tries to load *crt1* which is looking for *main*. So specify static linking.

```
% ld -e start -static hello.o -o hello
% ./hello
Hello world!
```

Answer (score -1):

In macOS 11.2 i used:

```
ld hello.o -L /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem
```