# How do I compile or build assembly programs on macOS with no libraries?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

The problem is that I have a filesystem in documents/assembly that goes like this:

test.s (from a Linux tutorial, using Linux system-call numbers):

```
    .global _start

    .text

_start:

    mov $60, %rax # exit
    mov $0, %rdi # return code 0
    syscall
```

compile.bash:

```
as -o test.o test.s && ld -e _start -o test.s test.o && chmod 777 test.o && (./test ; echo $?)
```

But when I try running compile.bash I get:

```
ld: dynamic executables or dylibs must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture x86_64
```

And when I try running test.o:

bash: ./test.o: cannot execute binary file

I'm using gnu assembler, But instead of gcc in the tutorial I say as.

I tried changing the command, But what happened was that it gave a lot of errors. I'm using macOS monteray version 12.5.1 (21G83). What I expected was it to print 0 when running the command, But it didn't.

(editor's note: x86-64 macOS uses different syscall numbers from x86-64 Linux, so building these instructions into an executable would run but exit with a segfault or bus error, but that's a separate problem.
For future readers looking for a tutorial, make sure it matches your OS as well as CPU architecture and mode (32 vs. 64-bit).)

Comment: You have the `as` part right. The link is `ld -e _start -o test test.o` which will compile `test` as an elf executable. You do NOT need to `chmod` as `ld` will set the execute bit on successful link. Then simply run `./test` (you were overwriting `test.s` with the executable with `ld -e _start -o test.s test.o`). Which, you should have been able to run `./test.s` at that point as it should have contained the elf executable with the execute bit set. (you could check with `ls -al test.s`)

Comment: @David C. Rankin Macos cannot run elf executables.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking Linux -- I should have checked the tags closer. I'm not sure what you would do different on mac. Link command would be the same -- you would just have whatever you call the executable type on mac instead of Linux. After compiling with `as` if you link as shown above, do you not end up with `test` created with the execute bit already set for you?

Comment: @AdamGewely They code you have written is for Linux.  MacOS requires different symbols for the entry point and different system calls.  Do not try to use a Linux tutorial for macOS.

Comment: @fuz What I think is that on macos you can use gcc, I tried gcc test.s and it made an a.out file. But when I ran ./a.out It said: Bad system call: 12

Comment: @fuz I also found a macos tutorial but it's 12 years ago, Are the commands going to be outdated?

Comment: @fuz it's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONZrKaJcT2I, But I think it's 32 bit.

Comment: @AdamGewely Once again, you'll need to write different code for macOS.  Unfortunately I'm not aware of a tutorial specifically for macOS.  32 bit code is no longer supported on macOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link object files without libSystem macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039667/link-object-files-without-libsystem-macos)

Answer (score 0):

> ld: dynamic executables or dylibs must link with libSystem.dylib for
> architecture x86_64

Try these lines:

```
as test.s -o test.o 
ld test.o -o test -macosx_version_min 13.0 -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem
```